# fabric not sending email notifications after new build

Tags: google-fabric, fastlane, fabric.io

New builds get uploaded to fabric. I have one-two groups with multiple users in fabric attached to the project. They are not receiving notifications on their test devices with every builds but sporadically. They can download the builds manually through the app, but the emails are not consistent with releases in beta. What does that depend on?